# What is the meaning of "many walks of life"?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I know that the meaning of walks of life is

> a person's occupation or position within society.

But in some cases, I don't get it. for example, someone has been saying something about how should we live and when he was finished, another guy said: "this is a good theme in many walks of life." I searched this term on the web and found nothing but examples that didn't make any sense either; like:

> My life has been forged by the many walks of life due to the fact that I have done many things but have committed to only a few. I call this venture of adventure the “many walks of life” because that is exactly what it is. Diversity Vs. Racism: A Challenge to Mankind
>   By Johnny Ishmel Henry

or:

> Mental Walks of Life. So many steps I have proceeded to take. Never really looking back, unless an error I make. There are so many roads I could follow with pride. There is no apparent reason, for my failures to hide. "Mental Walks of Life"
>   By Julio Toro

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A person said something about how people should live.

The second person said, "that advice is good for many different occupations and many different positions within society".

In short, the second person believes it is general advice that applies (or provides benefit) to most people without regard to their job or status.

Your first definition is good.  The second one uses it to state "I never really settled on any specific job or position within society."

The third example is a poem.  Poems relax the rules of English, to provide poetic structure, often in rhythm or sound.  To meet the poetic structure, sometimes they'll use words wrong, or play with meanings, altering the original sayings.  In this poem, they're not talking about occupation or position within society, but rather their imagination of their life as a journey, a literal (imaginary) walk.